# Will temporary file get deleted?

Tags: 8, files

On /admin/config/media/file-system, there is the *Delete temporary files after X hours* setting.

Does this specifically refer to files in /tmp or in the temporary folder? Does t possibly delete "unused" files?

I ask because I use `file_save_data()` to save files and I'm worried that Drupal decides to delete some of these files, as they won't be referenced anywhere except in my own custom table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files uploaded to managed files will be set as temporary. You need to set the file status as permanent, and add a usage, to prevent the file from being deleted.

Setting files as permanent can be done using [File::setPermanent()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Entity%21File.php/function/File%3A%3AsetPermanent/8.5.x). File usages can be added as follows:

```
$fid = 1; // The file ID
$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
$file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage');
$file_usage->add($file, 'mymodule', $entity_type, $entity_id);
```

This will add a 'usage' for the file. When deleted, you need to remove the file usage. Files that have been set to permanent, and have a file usage applied, will not be deleted.